# Apache Wicket - Custom servlet

Tags: java, apache, wicket

I am trying to integrate Wicket (1.5.16) with the "Single Sign-On". In this process, IdP posts a bunch of attributes back to the Wicket application using HTTP POST.

If I use , it looks for life cycle and also adds some numbers to the form, etc. I am looking for the following solution,
1) Create a Servlet/Some Wicket class which can receive the POST requests.
2) If SAML authentication is successful, forward to a private Internal .

Please let me know if you have any submissions.

Comment: At least in the newer wicket versions (>6) any Wicket Page can recieve Post requests and react to them. You just need a consturctor `public MyWicketPage(PageParameters pageParameters)` and then you can use that PageParameters object to get and react to Post parameters send to the page.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. Above constructor is available in 1.56 as well. I used it, but still I am seeing the number in the url. 

http://localhost:8080/mylogin?4-1.IFormSubmitListener-ssoResponseform

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap Wicket in another Servlet Filter. This way your Filter will receive the request first and may decide whether to process it or pass it to Wicket.

To accomplish this you just need to define your `<filter>` above/before Wicket's filter/servlet in web.xml.